# Get Firestore documents reference field's data using withConverter in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've **Appointments** collections with **student** and **teacher** as `reference` type along with other fields.

I want to get the list of Appointments using `CollectionReference.withConverter`. But because of reference fields, I'm not able to fetch them.

Example code:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('appts').withConverter<Appointment>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
        Map<String, dynamic> appt = snapshot.data()!;

        Student student = await appt['student'] // <---- Error as await is NOT allowed here
                .get()
                .then((studentSnapshot) => Student.fromMap(studentSnapshot.data()!));

        return Appointment.fromMap(
          snapshot.data()!
            ..['id'] = snapshot.id
            ..['student'] = student,
        );
      },
      toFirestore: (appointment, _) => ...,
    );
```

`await` is not allowed as `withConverter<Appointment>` expects `fromFirestore` to return `Appointment` object instead of `Future<Appointment>`

Without `await`, I'll get `Future<Student>`, and not sure how to map the complete document to **Student** type.

Is there anyway Flutter's Firestore auto-fetches the reference documents instead of I fetching them manually?

Comment: I've gone through all similarly titled questions, but none of them are for Flutter Firebase newer versions and doesn't use `withConverter`

Comment: how did you end up solving it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples that could help you with their documentation.

Using withCoverter in flutter
withConverter
Now, you can make use of withConverter in various places in order to change this type:

```
DocumentReference.withConverter:
final modelRef = FirebaseFirestore
    .instance 
    .collection('models') 
    .doc('123') 
    .withConverter<Model>( 
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!), 
        toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(), 
);
```

[DocumentReference.withConverter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/withConverter.html) (Public Documentation)

CollectionReference.withConverter:

```
final modelsRef = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('models')
      .withConverter<Model>( fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!), 
      toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(), 
);
```

[CollectionRefence.withConverter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/withConverter.html) (Public Documentation)

Query.withConverter:

```
final personsRef = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance 
      .collection('persons') 
      .where('age', isGreaterThan: 0) 
      .withConverter<Person>( fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Person.fromJson(snapshot.data()!), 
      toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(), 
);
```

[Query.withCoverter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/withConverter.html) (Public Documentation)

Here is also some documentation of firebase, flutter:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference